Are my dumplings properly cooked?
Recently I've been experimenting with homemade flour (or mostly-flour) dumplings. The recipes I've found all call for baking powder, but that's expensive and I don't keep it on hand, so I've been using baking soda with a bit of acid instead. For a cup of flour I typically have about 1/2 tsp of baking soda, perhaps 2 tbsp of vinegar or lemon juice etc., somewhere less than 1/2 cup of water, and perhaps a bit of other starches (a little cornstarch, leftover mashed potato, etc.) depending.
The thing is, when I drop these into water at a rolling boil, they come to the surface almost immediately, so I can't use that as an indicator of being done. Typically I keep them at a boil for a minute or so and then give them another 5 minutes or so on medium (not a simmer, but trying to make sure the pot doesn't boil over as starch leaks out into the water).
It seems that depending on the exact timing, size, wetness etc. these come out a couple different ways: either (with less cooking) the inside has a spongy appearance reminiscent of bread, or else (more cooking) it's chewy and completely solid and darkened, like mochi. I've had a couple come out where I cut them in half with a fork and they were visibly half-and-half, too.
I prefer the spongy, lighter texture, but does that mean they're underdone? For that matter, can I really be sure the chewy ones are fully cooked?
It seems awkward to try to temperature-probe a dumpling. I tried to look this up online but aside from cooking times in recipes I only saw a suggestion to toothpick-test dumplings as if they were cake. That seems highly implausible to me; after all, the outside will constantly be sticky wet stuff.

Because it doesn't seem to have been clear despite the tag and the text in the actual sentences with question marks: this is a food safety question. I understand well enough what steps I can take to get, or not get, the interior to appear a certain way, at least to the point that I could in principle practice to get it right consistently. But what I actually want to know is whether the ones that come out spongy are safe to eat.

"Sponginess" is unrelated to food safety. If you're just concerned with food safety, you just need to make sure the dumplings are cooked to the target temperature, either by measuring the temperature or by using a procedure which you know will achieve the target temperature.

Where do you live that baking powder is expensive?

@FuzzyChef well, it's far more expensive than baking soda, plus I'd need more of it. I'm sure it doesn't matter in absolute, per-serving terms, but for me it's the principle of the thing. And again, I literally wouldn't use it for anything else.

You may be able to change the interior consistency of your dumplings by changing the shape before you drop them into the water… if your dumpling’s leavening isn’t strong enough to break the outside shell that sets up almost immediately, a spherical dumpling will be much more dense than a more disk-like shape (as the disk will puff and expand to become closer to a sphere)

@Joe interesting. I'm hoping to get some experimentation in over the next month or so and I'll add that to my list of things to try. As far as the recipe goes, I quite liked the specific proportions I had last time, so I'll start there.

Baking powder costs me $2 a can.  Surely it can't be that much more expensive in Canada?  You're making a lot of work for yourself to adapt a recipe.

It is about four times as expensive as baking soda by weight, from what I have seen on shelves, here in Toronto, Canada. I don't expect you to understand my principles, however.

My findings after a few months of experimentation:

I couldn't get the toothpick test to work at all. Getting my dumplings to not just fall apart in the water completely requires making a quite stiff dough, which seems to stick to itself much better than to a toothpick even while raw. On the other hand, the wet exterior of a cooked dumpling sticks quite well to the toothpick.

I managed to get access to a kitchen thermometer with a digital readout, fast response and sufficiently narrow probe to use with my dumplings properly. I determined that there is no meaningful chance of a food safety risk here - dumplings boiled in water easily reach an internal temperature in excess of 200 F. Of course I tested this after extracting them from the water, but the measurement could still be confounded by water stuck to the surface. However, I also found that the dumplings can still hold an internal temperature over 145 F even after several minutes sitting out on a room temperature plate.

I have not found significant effects from varying the amount or type of acid used. Using more may make them a bit fluffier, but they tend to collapse after cooking anyway. (I have been using lemon juice recently; it somehow seems vulgar to add vinegar from the large 4L jugs as an ingredient.)

The relevant factors I have identified in getting the texture I want are 1) what else is added besides flour and water; 2) cooking time; and 3) dough stiffness. Again, a dough that isn't quite stiff will tend to just fall apart.


My current recipe uses a somewhat unorthodox ingredient, but I more or less get the results I want this way. The dumpling centers are a pleasure to bite into - substantial, but spongy and not chewy. My recipe follows:


150g white flour
50g plain potato chips
1/2 tsp baking soda
1 tbsp lemon juice
Water to make a stiff dough (generally, a bit less than 1/2 cup total liquid)

Finely crush the potato chips in a mixing bowl, using the back of a heavy cooking spoon. Mix the baking soda in well, then add the flour in parts (this is more about getting everything evenly distributed). Dilute the lemon juice with water in a 1/4 cup measure, add and stir into the flour mixture; gradually and conservatively add more water while kneading into a stiff dough. (A few potato chip flakes might be left behind; that's fine.)
Form the dough into 16 balls by repeatedly cutting in half and rolling, then drop into rapidly boiling salted water. (I do them in two batches in a medium sized pot.) Boil for about 90 seconds; then reduce heat to medium for about another 4 minutes, occasionally dunking the dumplings under the surface of the water.
Season to taste or serve with a sauce (despite the salt in the potato chips and water, and sodium in the baking soda, these come out fairly bland).

Perhaps instead of potato chips you could just use potato starch, which is a common ingredient for what you're trying to achieve. Or just mashed potatoes? Then you could probably forgo the baking soda + juice.

I've successfully made them with mashed potatoes as well - the texture is a bit different and they require less water. Potato starch is hard to find IMX, and very expensive compared to the equivalent amount of potato in other forms. I did try corn starch once because I happened to have it around; I remember not liking the result, but not why.

It looks like you're trying to reach a consistency like a that of a Baozi ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baozi ),  try to steam your dumplings it should prevent the Gelatinization ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starch_gelatinization ) of all of your dumpling.
If you want something different from a Baozi, some recipes require a dunk in boiling water like german Pretzels ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretzel ), italian Taralli ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taralli ) and Bagels ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagel ) but that dunk is then followed by cooking in the oven.
Following one of this techniques/recipes should help you to reach the result that you want.

Interesting; I've been to dim sum many years ago but didn't make the connection. But that still leaves me with the question of how to know when they're properly cooked. And actually I do like the wet, pasta-like exterior of a boiled dumpling.


[toothpick-testing dumplings] seems highly implausible to me; after all, the outside will constantly be sticky wet stuff.

The boiled outside of a (partially cooked) dumpling has an entirely different texture than the doughy inside. Having used a toothpick to test boiled puddings many times, I can tell you that the process works.
With that said, I think your problem arises from the variance in your ingredients and ratios. In particular, whether you use lemon juice or vinegar and the precise amount you use will have a far greater impact on the color and texture of the dumplings than the precise cooking time. Messing around with the recipe each time is something you should avoid until you can reliably achieve consistency in your results. That means following a recipe -- your own or someone else's, but the same recipe each time -- until you know what you can achieve, and can start building your knowledge of what tweaking that recipe will do.

My point is that the outside will leave residue on the toothpick seemingly no matter how long I cook the thing, because it doesn't stop having that different texture.

@KarlKnechtel Sure, just like the pudding. But the small amount of stuff which the surface will leave on the toothpick is entirely distinct from the stuff which undercooked dough will leave on the toothpick. Try dipping a toothpick into your raw dumpling dough: Does that look the same??
